# Liénard-Wiechert potentials in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, potential, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

In linearized gravity, we have.
$$
\Box \bar{h}_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{16 \pi G}{c^4}  T_{\mu \nu}
$$
Solving the equationg for a point mass, with a trajectory $\mathbf r_0(t')$:
$$
\rho(\mathbf r', t') = M \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf r' - \mathbf r_0(t'))
$$
we get:
$$
\bar{h}_{00} = -\frac{16\pi G M}{c^2}\left ( \frac{1}{\left (1 - \hat{\mathbf n} \cdot \boldsymbol \beta_0 \right ) |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|} \right ) _{t_r}
$$
where:
$$
\mathbf{\hat n} = \frac{\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|}. \\ \; \\ \;
\boldsymbol \beta_0 = \mathbf v_0 / c
$$
Would this line of reasoning be a good choice to start talking about gravitational waves and gravitational radiation? How do experts work with this; because this equation only allows a predetermined trajectory $\mathbf r_0(t')$, but this trajectory must be determined also from the equations, which as well, might depend on how much energy the system has lost, etc. It's a recursive relationship.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually asking here.  Can you expand on the actual question?  Also, is the long derivation actually necessary for your question?  Questions with a lot of notation often get closed as "check-my-work questions" around here (even if they're asking about a conceptual issue rather than verification.)